# Is the equational theory of commutative vN regular rings decidable?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, decidability

I wanted to check whether $A(x,y):=\frac{xy}{x+y}$ is an associative operation in every commutative [vN regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) ring. Now $A(-1,A(1,1))=A(-1,\frac{1}{2})=1\neq 0 =A(0,1)=A(A(-1,1),1)$. On the other hand, $\frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{1}{1/x+1/y}$, hence $A(x,A(y,z))=\frac{1}{1/x+1/y+1/z}=A(A(x,y),z)$. I soon realized that $\frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{1}{(y/y)/x+(x/x)/y}\neq\frac{1}{1/x+1/y}$.

This made me wonder whether equality is decidable in principle for this sort of term expressions. So I browsed a [list information about classes of mathematical structures](http://www.math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/) for a summary of the properties of [commutative regular rings](http://www.math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/commutative_regular_rings), but the [equational theory](http://www.math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/equational_theory) field was left empty for this structure. (I guess the reason is that the generalized inverse operation $^{-1}$ should have been part of the signature, otherwise the meaning of this field is ambiguous.) Because this structure is a variety (=equational class, here I assume that $^{-1}$ is part of the signature), if two terms are equal, then this can be proved by term rewriting. If two terms are not equal, then this should be provable by substituting specific values from a specific commutative vN regular ring, for which the two terms evaluate to different values. It is easy to see that this commutative ring can always be chosen to be a field. If a finite field would always be enough, then the equational theory of commutative vN regular rings should be decidable.

> Is there any reason why a finite field should not be enough for proving inequality?
>   Is there any "much simpler" way to see that the equational theory is decidable?

---

**Edit** There was some confusion regarding the generalized inverse operation $^{-1}$ in the comments. Similar to groups, neither $1$ nor $^{-1}$ are needed in the [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) to define commutative vN regular rings by first-order axioms. But when talking about the equational theory, it certainly makes a difference whether they are included or not. Both groups and commutative vN regular rings can be treated as [varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)), because suitable signatures and defining equations are [well known](http://www.math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/inverse_semigroups) and [easy to prove](https://gentzen.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/algebraic-characterizations-of-inverse-semigroups-and-strongly-regular-rings/). (For commutative vN regular rings, the ring is an inverse semigroup under multiplication, hence adding $^{-1}$ to the signature and $xx^{-1}x=x$ and $x^{-1}xx^{-1}=x^{-1}$ to the equations of commutative rings is enough.) But to make things confusing, (non-commutative) vN regular rings cannot be treated as varieties, because the inverse element need not be unique, and hence the identity $xx^{-1}y^{-1}y=y^{-1}yxx^{-1}$ may fail (this identity would hold if all inverse elements were unique).

Comment: If some equation does not hold in all com. rings, it fails in some finitely generated com. ring, hence in some finitely generated com. free ring, and since the latter is residually a finite field, the equation fails in some finite field.

Comment: But I'm somewhat confused about the meaning of ``A(x,y)" is an (associative) operation" (in a given ring $R$): it's not defined on $R\times R$ because the denominator need be invertible...

Comment: @YCor The generalized inverse operation $()^{-1}$ in a field is the normal inverse operation for non-zero elements, and maps zero to zero. Hence it satisfies $xx^{-1}x=x$ as required.

Comment: @Ycor The statement that the equation will fail in some finitely generated free commutative regular ring is a bit trivial, because one just needs to use the free variables from the two terms to get the required finite set of generators. So the statement "and the latter is residually a finite field" implies that my first question actually asks whether the free commutative regular ring of $n$-generators is residually finite, i.e. that for every of its elements I can find a homomorphism to a finite ring.

Comment: Thomas, every finitely generated associative commutative ring is residually finite. (For free rings (= polynomial rings), this is almost obvious.)

Comment: @AntonKlyachko The free commutative von Neumann regular ring of $n$-generators is different from the free commutative ring, because the generalized inverse operation $()^{-1}$ allows to form elements otherwise not available. Hence it is not so obvious whether it is residually finite. Maybe the terminology here is a bit unhappy.

Comment: How do you define a free commutative von Neumann regular ring (and show their existence)?

Comment: @Ycor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object, i.e. via a universal property. It exists, because a commutative vN regular ring is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra). Free objects on $n$-generators exists for a variety (equational class) and can be represented as the quotient of the term algebra (on the generators) over the congruence relation generated by the equations. This is proved in universal algebra texts in connection with Birkhoff's theorem.

Comment: When you say that vN regular rings form a variety, do you mean actually vN regular rings in which quasi-inverses are given by a specified operation? These aren't the same as vN regular rings in which mere existence of quasi-inverses is asserted, are they? (Ah, never mind; I think you address this point in the post.)

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel I don't think the VN regular ring form a variety: for instance a domain is VNregular iff it's a field, and a subring of a field need not be a field...

Comment: @YCor I think the explanation is that the signature of vN regular rings in the sense used by Thomas Klimpel is not the same as that of rings; he's including a unary operation $\phi$ such that $a\phi(a)a = a$ for all $a$.

Comment: @YCor I added an appendix to the question trying to clarify these things. The vN regular rings don't form a variety, but for different reasons than you state. The commutative vN regular rings do form a variety, or at least can be treated as a variety. The vN regular rings with unique inverses can be treated as a variety, here the identity $xx^{-1}yy^{-1}=yy^{-1}xx^{-1}$ holds because of the uniqueness and is sufficient to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Thomas, could you give a link to the "well-known" signature and equations for your notion? (It has to be less well-known than the notions of variety and signature, which you do provide links for.) [I also don't understand why my own guess is insufficient -- add to the theory of rings an unary operation satisfying $a\phi(a)a = a$. That *clearly* yields a variety, and witnesses the property required of vN rings as defined in the WP article.]

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I think for commutative vnr you want also $\phi(a)a\phi(a)=\phi(a)$. Otherwise you might get a weak inverse but not the inverse. If a is idempotent then you want $\phi(a)=a$ not $1$.

Comment: I don't see how you can map Q as a vnr to Z/p. Any ring homomorphism is an abelian group homomorphism. Q has no proper finite index subgroup. So it is not residually finite as a ring.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I wanted to map $x=\frac{z}{n}$ to $z_pn_p^{-1}$. You are right that this mapping is not a homomorphism, because $p$ and $1/p$ would be mapped to $0$, but $1=p*1/p$ gets mapped to $1$. I will remove the corresponding part from the question.

Comment: @YCor Note that $x_0=0$, i.e. $\phi(0)=0$ can be deduced from the available identities. The notion is basically equivalent to a subdirect product of fields. One reason why this notion might be useful is that the free commutative vN regular ring with $n$-generators exists. If the equational theory should turn out to be decidable, then this would give one more reason to suspect that this notion is interesting. If not, then maybe it's not that interesting after all.

Comment: But could you say explicitly, for say a commutative ring, *all* the axioms the require for $\phi$ to define a commutative VN-ring with unary operation? I understand you have $\phi(x)x\phi(x)=\phi(x)$. Note that the wiki page would rather suggest $x\phi(x)x=x$, which is not equivalent.

Comment: @Ycor The equations $x\phi(x)x=x$ and $\phi(\phi(x))=x$ in addition to the normal commutative ring equations are sufficient. (I remember that the equation $\phi(\phi(x))=x$ was derivable from the other equations, but at least for an inverse semigroup, it was an awfully long derivation.)

Comment: I know nothing about von Neumann regular rings, however such an identity (or any quantifier-free formula for that matter) fails in a field iff it fails in an algebraically closed field (by embedding in algebraic closure) iff it fails in an a.c.f. of finite characteristic (due to the compactness theorem) iff it fails in some $\tilde{\mathbb F_p}$ (as all a.c.f. of the same characteristic are elementarily equivalent) iff it fails in a finite field (as every finitely generated subfield of $\tilde{\mathbb F_p}$ is finite). You only need the first step anyway as the theory of a.c.f. is decidable.

Comment: Are commutative vNr rings in the signature with ${}^{-1}$ the same thing as meadows? http://mathoverflow.net/a/3015

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel: no in this context you can't derive $\phi(\phi(x))=x$ from the other axioms (i.e. the axioms of meadow, see Emil's link), otherwise you can prescribe any nonzero value to $\phi(0)$ and it only contradicts $\phi(\phi(x))=x$. So we can call the latter structure "involutive meadow".

Comment: Actually, the axioms in Loop Space’s answer seem to be incomplete. In Bergstra’s papers, meadows are defined as involutive.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, they are the same thing as meadows. I didn't know "meadows" before, but I have the impression that Bergstra’s papers will answer most of my open questions with respect to "meadows" (and commutative vN regular rings).

Comment: @YCor One can derive $\phi(\phi(x))=x$ from $x\phi(x)x=x$ and $\phi(x)x\phi(x)=\phi(x)$. I tried to collect some typical algebraic characterizations of inverse semigroups and strongly regular rings now, see https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6x6GQ82vuH_REVOTDZqc09WZ3c&usp=sharing (there are also some prover9 and e-prover files, just in case the proofs are not convincing enough...)

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel I said that I used the definition of meadow given by Emil's link, which does not include $\phi(x)x\phi(x)=\phi(x)$. Alone, $x\phi(x)x=x$ does not put any constraint to $\phi(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emil Jeřábek's comment explains how to prove that the equational theory of commutative vN regular rings decidable:

> I know nothing about von Neumann regular rings, however such an identity (or any quantifier-free formula for that matter) fails in a field iff it fails in an algebraically closed field (by embedding in algebraic closure) iff it fails in an a.c.f. of finite characteristic (due to the compactness theorem) iff it fails in some $\tilde{\mathbb F}_p$ (as all a.c.f. of the same characteristic are elementarily equivalent) iff it fails in a finite field (as every finitely generated subfield of $\tilde{\mathbb F}_p$ is finite). You only need the first step anyway as the theory of a.c.f. is decidable.

Jan Bergstra (see "meadows", also mentioned by Emil Jeřábek in a comment) told me that [Komori in "Free algebras over all fields and pseudo-fields"](http://komoriyuichi.web.fc2.com/ListOfPapers.html) and [Ono in "Equational theories and universal theories of fields"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1230396550) proved that the equational theory of commutative regular rings is decidable. This is theorem 4.3 in Ono (which uses similar ideas as in Emil's comment). I haven't accessed Komori's paper, but Ono's paper confirms that Komori's paper also contains a proof of this fact.

---

Regarding the confusion about the inverse operation $^{-1}$ and treating commutative regular rings as a variety (equational class), I collected some (related) elementary facts together with complete proofs in a pdf document and a related blog-post [Algebraic characterizations of inverse semigroups and strongly regular rings](https://gentzen.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/algebraic-characterizations-of-inverse-semigroups-and-strongly-regular-rings/).